# Wordpress - use $wpdb->update and limit 1

Tags: mysql, wordpress

It's probably a stupid question but I'm trying to use `$wpdb->update` instead of $wpdb->query but I'm not sure how to use limit 1. So instead of

```
$wpdb->query("update {$wpdb->prefix}vp_pms_group_users set read = '1', seen = '1', time_seen = '{$date_time_seen}' where message_id = '{$last_message_id}' and group_id = '{$group_id}' and to_username = '{$session_uid}' and read = '0' limit 1");
```

I've tried with

```
$wpdb->update($wpdb->prefix . "vp_pms_group_users", array(
                'read' => '1',
                'seen' => '1',
                'time_seen' => $date_time_seen,
            ),
            array(
                'message_id' => $last_message_id,
                'group_id' => $group_id,
                'to_username' => $session_uid,
                'read' => '0',
            ),
            LIMIT 1 //????
);
```

Should I use limit after the array or inside it?
Thanks.

Comment: Not possible, if you look at the code in the `insert` method, it runs this query: `UPDATE $table SET $fields WHERE $conditions;` and there's no filters available to add a limit..

Comment: Having looked further, there is a filter in the `query` method, which is called directly by the `insert` method, it would be tricky to filter out that exact query to add the limit, but it is available.. `$query = apply_filters('query', $query);`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer, it's not pretty, but based on looking through the method chain within `$wpdb` it's possibly the only way to achieve what you're after, and still use `$wpdb->update()`.

**Step 1.** 
Make your update with a unique parameter which you'll later replace, note that this must be the last parameter passed to the `WHERE` clause, otherwise replacing it with `LIMIT 1` will cause a syntax error in your SQL statement.

Something like:

```
$wpdb->update(
    $wpdb->prefix . "vp_pms_group_users", 
    array(...),
    array(
        ...
        'MyReplacementLimit' => 1
    )
);
```

This should give you an SQL statement like so:

```
UPDATE vp_pms_group_users SET ... WHERE ... AND MyReplacementLimit = 1;
```

**Step 2:**
Now you can use the `query` filter to replace that fake clause with a limit...

```
add_filter('query', function ($query) {
    return str_replace('AND MyReplacementLimit = 1', 'LIMIT 1', $query);
});
```

This is **untested** and is based purely on reading through the code available in `$wpdb`. It may need a few tweaks to get working correctly.

**A simpler solution:**
You could always just use SQL directly, so long as you're using `$wpdb->prepare()` it's probably easier to read, and more understandable than the above approach.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to use your method!

Answer (score 1):

you should change Previous answer add_filter to this:

```
add_filter('query', function ($query) {
    return str_replace("AND `MyReplacementLimit` = '1'", 'LIMIT 1', $query);
});
```